# Picking up desirable objects from a pile

Tags: ingress

Nowadays I have seen a few piles where people have discarded L1-L3 resonators, XMP bursters and (for some reason) even some portal keys; presumably because of the new 2k limits.

Unfortunately, when I came across such a trove; my only option was to repeatedly 'acquire' items one by one. Even when I saw the flash of green that indicated portal keys, it was covered by resonators & bursters so I kept getting those first.

- Is there an easier way to pick up only items that you want, something like filtering for only bursters or portal keys in a mixed group?
- Can we pick up 'all' items, or even better 'all of X type' items in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scanner app at version 1.12.5 enforces the new limit but doesn't give a way to do bulk, or type specific pickups. I too wish you could filter the view to hide items, or items of a certain type.

Comment: What's the new limit?  I haven't played for a little over a week, so haven't heard about this yet?

Comment: I think it's the 2000 items in inventory (per player) limit.